# How is an empty __init__.py file correct?

Tags: python

I have several, empty, `__init__.py` files in my packages. Is it correct if I keep them empty or do I have to place a `pass` inside them?

Are there any PEP, or other, guidelines about the subject?

Comment: `pass` is needed only where an indented block is required (after `def`, `if`, `while` et cetera) and you want to leave it empty.

Answer (score 62):

Empty files are [perfectly fine](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

Depending on what you plan to do it's a good place to import public stuff from the modules in your package so people can simply use `from yourpackage import whatever` instead of having to use `from yourpackage.somemodule import whatever`.

Comment: This especially useful for creating a simplifying _Facade_ for a complex package.  
Assume your package has 10 submodules each containing 50 things, but a majority of users will need to use (and know about) only 12 of those 500 things.  
Then it is super nice for them to find these 12 all in `yourpackage` instead of confusingly spread over 10 submodules they do not really want to know about.