# Can we create multiple views in django

Tags: django

I am doing an online shopping site project in django. I have the following modules
-Admin
-Moderators
-Employees
-Service
-Users.
If i write all the views in single views.py it will be mess,
So can I create a Folder named Views and create multiple views (adminViews.py, userviews.py etc) and write functions in it?
Is it a good way?
Also do i need to create folder that contain multiple Forms file for different modules??

Comment: Yes you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921771/split-views-py-in-several-files)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split views.py in several files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921771/split-views-py-in-several-files)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually there's exactly one `views.py` file per app, but this is just by convention. `views.py` is just a regular python file and you can use any name you want. (Make sure to update to imports in the `urls.py`).

I'd recommend creating a new module called `views` to collect multiple views (adminViews.py, userviews.py etc)

Note: A python module is just a folder with an `__init__py` file in it.

Your new folder structure might look like this:
[image]

You can import your views like this:

```py
# urls.py

from .views.adminViews import YourAdminView
```

Comment: What we should add in the __init__. py file

Comment: you can leave it empty. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863268/how-is-an-empty-init-py-file-correct

Comment: But do i need to delete init.py file which was there already

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this works not only for `views.py` but also for `models.by` or `tests.py`.

See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921911/621690) for more details.

I still leave this answer here, because I would like to mention that large files could also indicate that you might want to split your single app into multiple apps.

#### Splitting views.py or models.py

To keep your imports like for example:

```
from myproject.myapp.views import UserListView
```

where `UserListView` was previously in the file `views.py` but is moved to `views/users.py`, add the following to `views/__init__.py`:

```
from myproject.myapp.views.users import UserListView
# alternative in __init__.py:
from .users import UserListView
```

You can then keep all the imports as they were before splitting into multiple files. The same works when splitting models into multiple files.

#### Splitting tests.py

There is no need to add the test classes to `tests/__init__.py`. The tests are found as long as they follow the naming conventions for tests.

#### Splitting admins.py

I never did split `admins.py` but I guess it would work, as well.

However, if your `admins.py` contains a lot of models this could also indicate that you actually need to split your app into multiple apps.