# Using "python -m" to call Python script not working

Tags: python, terminal

Basically the title. File structure below with code examples.

Relevant project structure:

```
drf/
├─ backend/
├─ py_client/
│  ├─ basic.py
├─ venv/
├─ requirements.txt
```

I know that using "python -m" is best practice for venvs, and I understand that the reason for this is to use the currently activated Python version, managing dependencies etc. etc.

But what I don't understand is why it affects running a script via CLI the way it does.

##### Method + Response 1:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\cjrow\DjangoProjects\drf> python -m py_client/basic.py
C:\Users\cjrow\DjangoProjects\drf\venv\Scripts\python.exe: Error while finding module specification for 'py_client/basic.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py_client/basic'). Try using 'py_client/basic' instead of 'py_client/basic.py' as the module name.
```

So I followed the suggestion and removed the `.py`, though I don't even understand why that was a suggestion.

##### Method + Result 2:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\cjrow\DjangoProjects\drf> python -m py_client/basic
C:\Users\cjrow\DjangoProjects\drf\venv\Scripts\python.exe: No module named py_client/basic
```

This obviously didn't work at all. So I tried without `-m`:

##### Method + Result 3

(`basic.py` just contains `print("It's working")`:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\cjrow\DjangoProjects\drf> python py_client/basic.py
It's working
```

And then, just out of curiosity:

##### Method + Result 4:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\cjrow\DjangoProjects\drf> python py_client/basic   
C:\Users\cjrow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\cjrow\\DjangoProjects\\drf\\py_client\\basic': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I understand why 3 works and I understand why 4 doesn't work, but I don't understand why neither 1 nor 2 work.

Thanks!

Comment: If you just want to run a script, "python myscript.py" When you install a module with a setup.py then the -m flag is more useful.

Answer (score 1):

When you use -m flag you are telling python to read the script as a module, this requires a special file in the folder where your script is with the name `__init__.py` more info here [Why **init**.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863268/how-is-an-empty-init-py-file-correct#:%7E:text=Empty%20files%20are%20perfectly%20fine,on%20the%20module%20search%20path.).
Then you can use -m flag.
I reproduced you error with the following structure.

```
b/
|--a/
|--|script.py
```

Solved adding.

```
b/
|--a/
|--|script.py
|--|__init__.py
```

file `script.py` contains

```
print('hi')
```

b contains a and a contains script.py and **init**.py so from terminal I can do `python3 -m b.a.script`

```
hi
```

if I am in folder where b is or if you are in b itself then `python3 -m a.script`

```
hi
```

Or in a itself `python3 -m script`

```
hi
```

Hope this helps, this is my first answer.

Comment: In what folder are you whe  you call `python3 -m a-script? are you in b or in root?